# Why is my LibGDX ImageButton only being detected once?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, imagebutton

I am making a game in Android Studio using LibGDX, and I am attempting to add a pause button to the top corner of the main game screen. My game has been pausing fine thus far, but I have only been pausing when a key was pressed. Now I want to add a button, and I got the button to render in the top right corner, but when I press it it only works once. The first time I press it, my game pauses fine. But every time I try and pause it after that, it doesn't work. I have used extensive log statements and debugging and have found out that after pressing it once, the Listener doesn't even detect the button being pressed at all, so I am lead to believe that is where my issue is.

This is how I create my button in my HUD class, which is the class that prints the score onscreen at all times:

```
TextureAtlas buttonAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("Buttons.pack"));
    Skin skin = new Skin();
    skin.addRegions(buttonAtlas);
    ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle style = new ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle();
    style.imageUp = skin.getDrawable("PauseButton");
    style.imageDown = skin.getDrawable("PauseButton");
    style.imageChecked = skin.getDrawable("PauseButton");
    button = new ImageButton(style);
```

I then added a Listener to check if the button is clicked:

```
button.addListener(new ClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y)
        {
            Gdx.app.log("","Button was pressed");

            pauseGame();
        }
    });
```

The method pauseGame() that is called after the Listener detects the button being clicked:

```
public void pauseGame()
{
    Gdx.app.log("","Game should be pausing");

    screen.pauseGame();
}
```

screen is a class called PlayScreen that is the main game screen for my game, and its pauseGame() method works perfectly. The game before you press the pause button is as follows(You can see the pause button in the top right corner, please excuse the graphics, they are simply placeholders until I make and add my own graphics):
[Game before pause](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M62tb.png)

In my main PlayScreen class, this is my pauseGame method:

```
public void pauseGame()
{
    gamePaused = true;

    if(music.isPlaying())
    {
        musicType = type.NORMAL;
        music.pause();
    }
    else if(barrageMusic.isPlaying())
    {
        musicType = type.BARRAGE;
        barrageMusic.pause();
    }

    createPauseWindow();
}
```

And then in my render method, I call another method called update. In this method, I update my viewport, my HUD, and create new enemies. This is the only method that stops being called when gamePaused is true. The rest of my rendering and other necessary updates still take place. I have been trying to fix this problem for a long time but no matter how many different ways I rewrite the code to pause the game or make different listeners, the pause button only works one time and then never again.

Comment: Do you stop going through your game logic while the game is paused?

Comment: Show Screen's pauseGame method

Comment: @QBrute, I don't stop all of my game logic, and any of that logic would start up again when the game resumes anyway. It's when I try to pause the game a second time that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried with `touchDown` method?
It might works.

```java
button.addListener(new ClickListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                pause();
                event.handle();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

And try to change to a global variable base, a variable that is checked inside your render method and if it is true call the pause method. That to avoid call complex actions like pause from a listener, something like this:

```java
button.addListener(new ClickListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                pause = true;
                event.handle();
                return true;
            }
        });

...

public void render(){
    if (pause == true){
        pauseGame();
    }
    ...
}
```

It simplifies your listener and let you find easily your error.

Comment: I have tried this and tried it again with your advice in mind, but it still didn't work. The game would pause once and never again.